# How to assign more than one IP address to a container?

Tags: docker

Following the steps [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/how-to-assign-static-ip-in-docker-for-windows-for-linux-container), I've created my own internal network to allow containers to communicate with each other. Each have an IP address from the subnet I want.

I would like some containers to have specific (i.e. statically assigned), several, private IP addresses from this range. If I create a container with:

```
docker run -d --name steve5 --ip 10.0.0.6 --ip 10.0.0.7 --network my-net docker/getting-started
```

This is accepted without error, but only the last `--ip` argument takes effect.

EDIT: I found [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/assign-more-than-one-ip-address-to-a-container) that's possible with the Docker run argument `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` to then add more IP addresses inside the container itself, using e.g.

```
ip address add 10.0.0.8/8 dev eth0
```

However is there a way to script the adding of more IPs to the container when creating/starting it?

Also: `docker inspect` only returns the first assigned address, not the one added with `ip address add ...`